# Sort table with gaps

Tags: lua, lua-table

I got a table which is not meant to be sorted in a way I need it to be sorted at a specific point. 
Thus, I cannot sort the table while creation but have to sort it when needed.

Problem is, there are plenty gabs in the indeces and the Values I want to sort here are nested.

Simplified model:

```
table = {
  [1]  = { a = 1 , b = 31231, c = { c1 = "foo" , true } },
  [8]  = { a = 2 , b = 5231 , c = { c1 = "bar" , true } },
  [92] = { a = 8 , b = 2    , c = { c1 ="asdgköbana" , false } },
}
```

Now I want to sort this table by length of c[1]. 
How can I do that in the fastest way? Length of table in first dimension will stay under 100 entries.

Indices don't need to be kept. So by a table with 3 entries, it's okay when last index is [3] after the portage. Basicly in this case, I only use the index to identifies neighbors, they have no prior use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `table` as a variable kills the `table` library, which you need to get the `sort` function.

Try the code below. Note that it makes a new table to hold the sorted list but reuses the internal tables.

```
local t = {
  [1]  = { a = 1 , b = 31231, c = { c1 = "foo" , true } },
  [8]  = { a = 2 , b = 5231 , c = { c1 = "bar" , true } },
  [92] = { a = 8 , b = 2    , c = { c1 ="asdgköbana" , false } },
} 

local s = {}
for k,v in pairs(t) do
    s[#s+1]=v
end

table.sort(s,function (a,b)
    return #a.c.c1 < #b.c.c1
end)

for k,v in ipairs(s) do
    print(k,v.a,v.c.c1)
end
```